# Outlook add-in: Is there a way to get the text from email compose with new lines?

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I'm having an issue that I'm not so sure how to overcome it.

I'm able to get the message compose text, but I need to get new lines as well (ENTER clicked).

so if the message is:

```
"This is an example
for new line"
```

I will get in the `body.getAsync`
This is an example `\n` for new line

```js
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
      mailboxItem = Office.context.mailbox.item;
    }
      
    function validateBody(event) {
      mailboxItem.body.getAsync("text", { asyncContext: event }, sendToServer);
    }
    
    function sendToServer(asyncResult){
      //NOW HERE I NEED THE TEXT WITH NEW LINES
      //(like:This is an example \n for new line)
    }
```

If the is no way to do this, then is there a way to get the item body as plain javascript object?
 and add to it:

```js
item.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  // Number 13 is the "Enter" key on the keyboard
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    // DO THIS
  }
});
```

Comment: The Unix-style new lines (character code 10) are present in the string return in asyncResult.value.  Maybe you need to convert them to Windows-style (slash-r slash-n) for your application needs?

Comment: which platform are you getting this issue on? Is it desktop client or outlook on web?